# cant send params via navigation navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want to send parameter name from login screen to home screen via router but data object not defined

> TypeError: undefined is not object (evaluating
>   'navigation.state.params.name'

**login screen**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.buttonContainer}
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { name: 'Erry' })}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>MASUK</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**my router**

```
export const LoginStack = SwitchNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack
  }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    }
  });

export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  }
});
```

**Home Screen**

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.name}`,
      headerStyle : {
          backgroundColor: '#f39c12',
      },
      headerTitleStyle :{
          color: '#353b48',
      },
  });
```

any idea ?

Comment: what is mean by SwitchNavigator

Comment: i use SwitchNavigator login to home because HomeStack actually so much another screen

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away.

You'd better not use `SwitchNavigator`, you can see the [correct example](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow).

And you'd better judge the `params` is empty or not:

```
const params = navigation.state.params || {};
const title = params.name || 'default title';
```

Comment: in your example loginScreen navigate to App instead of AuthLoading ?